# BLACKENING on edge of pear tree leaves & shoots

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, pear

I can’t figure out what this is on my dwarf pear tree. I’ve looked around the plant and can’t see any pests. The tree is 3-4 years old. I have had the tree for two years.

It’s 3-4 years old and planted in a container and left in the garden. I am based in London UK, to give you an idea of climate.

+The edge of the leaves are turning dark black 
+Black/brown spots on other leaves
+New Shoots seem to be black as well

I think there maybe two infections but I really can’t tell. Any help would be great.

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Where are you located, is the tree new? Planted in the ground or a pot?

Comment: I’m in the UK, London.. it’s planted in a fairly large pot in a south easy facing garden.

Comment: Also, I’ve had the tree for two years

Comment: I have never had it but you should check out "fire blight"  which attacks pears.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with my dwarf pear.  I did everything to try to say it, but nothing worked.  I found out that pears easily fall victim to a virus and as near as I could find out, there is no cure.  It looks like aphids have moved in as well?  If theleaves are sticky feeling, that is a sign of aphids.

Comment: The leaves aren’t sticky or anything. I have a grape vine, apple, lemon, cherry and olive trees,  all young. Will it affect the other trees? Should I dispose of the pear tree if it can’t be saved?